# Python: accessing array's / list's first element, with Z3 datatypes

Tags: python, arrays, list, z3py

In Python (Collab), I have the following variable `c`:

```
array([x_1 > 1000, y_1 < x_1 + 1], dtype=object)
```

Where `x_1 > 1000` and `y_1 < x_1 + 1` are z3 (py) variables / predicates. I would like to access its 'first element': the array / list `[x_1 > 1000, y_1 < x_1 + 1]`, entirely, but I am not capable.

These are the attempts I have made:

- `c[0]` yields `x_1 > 1000` (and, of course, `c[1]` yields
  `y_1 < x_1 + 1`).
- `a, b = c`  yields, again, `a` to be `x_1 > 1000` and
  `b` to be `y_1 < x_1 + 1`.
- `c.0` yields an error (and, obviously, so does `c.1`).

The reason why I want to access that element of the array is I want to perform the following z3 computation in an automatic way:

`And([x_1 > 1000, y_1 < x_1 + 1])`. So it would be nice to make something like `And(c[0])`.

This is probably a beginner mistake, but I cannot see it. Any help?

---

EDIT:

Note that, the problem of asking `And(c[0])`, is that I am doing `And(x_1 > 1000)`, while I would like to perform: `And(x_1 > 1000, y_1 < x_1 + 1)` (i.e., apparently `And(c[0],c[1])`.

Comment: What happens now when you do a `And(c[0])`?

Comment: The result is a single-parameter conjunction, I have edited the post to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always best to post full code segments, i.e., those that can be loaded and executed by readers without filling up the missing parts. Otherwise it's really hard to replicate/understand what you're trying to do and what error you're getting.

I don't use collab (not sure what it is), but if `c` is a list, you can use the `*` notation to turn its contents to arguments. Something like this:

```py
from z3 import *

x_1, y_1 = Ints('x_1 y_1')
c = [x_1 > 1000, y_1 < x_1 + 1]

s = Solver()
s.add(And(*c))
print(s.sexpr())
```

This prints:

```
(declare-fun x_1 () Int)
(declare-fun y_1 () Int)
(assert (and (> x_1 1000) (< y_1 (+ x_1 1))))
```

This'll work correctly regardless of how many elements you have in the list `c`. Note that this has nothing to do with z3, but it is a Python idiom.

I'm not sure about your `array` construct; but if it can be turned into a list, the above trick should work. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I completely agree, I tried to keep my example as most minimalist as possible, but I forgot to put ```x_1, y_1 = Ints('x_1 y_1')``` as you did. I apologise. As for the response, that suits, completely. Did not know not the ```*``` notation, is there any equivalent? I tried to perform ```params = *c``` and raises an error.

Comment: '*' is a Pythonism to turn a list into a sequence of arguments. Here's a good write-up about it: https://treyhunner.com/2018/10/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/

Comment: Note that the same effect as with ```*(c)``` can be achieved with ```list(c)```.